# Краш приложения с ошибкой E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Tags: java, android

Крашит приложение при нажатии на кнопку, полная ошибка:

```
2021-03-18 07:28:44.060 10712-10712/com.slavatar.unimedia E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.slavatar.unimedia, PID: 10712
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:414)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448)
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425)
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot execute task: the task has already been executed (a task can be executed only once)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:716)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:671)
    at com.slavatar.unimedia.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:409) 
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7448) 
    at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1119) 
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7425) 
    at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28305) 
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947) 
    2021-03-18 07:28:44.124 10712-10712/com.slavatar.unimedia I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10712 
    SIG: 9
```

Код MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    HttpActivity httpActivity = new HttpActivity();
    EditText adressEntry;
    EditText passwordEntry;
    Button startBtn;

    String web;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.auth);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.startBtn:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;

            case R.id.stopPauseVid:
                httpActivity.execute("http://192.168.0.6:5000/1234/code/1");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В ошибке же написано: **a task can be executed only once**.
Это означает, что переиспользовать `AsyncTask` нельзя и вы должны на каждый запуск создавать новый экземпляр:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.startBtn:
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                break;

            case R.id.stopPauseVid:
                httpActivity = new HttpActivity();
                httpActivity.execute("http://192.168.0.6:5000/1234/code/1");
        }
    }
```